# In Azure Storage account for Azure Function, where is the function code stored?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

This is a rookie question...
I have deployed an Azure linux nodejs function to Azure as a Function App. There is an associated storage account created as well.

When I browse through the storage account, I see there are files in Container and File Share, but none of them is storing the nodejs code I wrote for the azure function.

In Containers:
[image]

In File Shares:
[image]

If I click into the function name in File Shares:
[image]

I have browsed through the folders and there is no nodejs code I wrote for the function.
Questions:

1. What are these files in Container and File Share?
2. Where is the actual nodejs function code stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy your Node.js function as a Function App, the actual function code will be available in the function app itself.

- Go to `function app=>Overview=>click on your deployed function=>CODE+TEST`.

[image]

[image]

- The files available in the Container and File Share are related to the underlying infrastructure and metadata of the Function App.
- Access keys and other important service-related data will be available in the storage account.

1. **Blob Storage/Container:**
   Containers are used to store the data consumed or generated by the functions, such as logs, input/output data.
2. **File Share:**
   The File Share is used for storing the configuration files which the functions need to access during its execution.

- You can find the project files in site=>wwwroot=>function folder:

[image]

[image]

***Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations?tabs=azure-cli)  to know more about the usage of storage account and its services in Azure functions.***